# fopen matlab code in Python

Tags: python, matlab

I have the following code written in Matlab:

```
>>> fid = fopen('filename.bin', 'r', 'b')
>>> %separated r and b
>>> dim = fread(dim, 2, 'uint32');
```

if I use a "equivalent" code in Python

```
>>> fid = open('filename.bin', 'rb')  
>>> dim = np.fromfile(fid, dtype=np.uint32)
```

I got a different value of dim when I use Python.

Someone knows how to open this file with permission like Matlab ('r' and 'b' separated) in Python?

Thanks in advance,

Rhenan

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Matlab docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html) I learn that your third parameter 'b' stands for Big-Endian ordering, is not a permission.

Most probably Numpy uses the little-endian order on your machine. To fix the problem try to specify explicitly the ordering in Numpy (as you do in Matlab):

```
>>> fid = open('filename.bin', 'rb')
>>> dim = np.fromfile(fid, dtype='>u4')
```

the `dtype` string stands for Big-Endian ('>'), unsigned integer ('u'), 4-bytes number.

See also [Data type objects (dtype)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#arrays-dtypes-constructing) in Numpy reference.